# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in node_modules\minio\dist\main and node_modules\mkdirp in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, minio

I am trying to get images from minio bucket in UI, so I installed minio using `npm install --save minio` then I imported it in one jsx file using `const Minio = require("minio");` So I started getting error as,

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/minio/dist/main/minio.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Solutions\ui\node_modules\minio\dist\main'
 @ ./node_modules/minio/dist/main/minio.js 13:33-46
 @ ./src/SearchResultPreview/search-result-preview.jsx
 @ ./src/Search/search.jsx
 @ ./src/search-with-context.jsx
 @ ./src/sme/Sme.js
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Solutions\ui\node_modules\mkdirp'
 @ ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/minio/dist/main/minio.js
 @ ./src/SearchResultPreview/search-result-preview.jsx
 @ ./src/Search/search.jsx
 @ ./src/search-with-context.jsx
 @ ./src/sme/Sme.jsx
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.jsx
```

please help me with the problem, due to **Error: Can't resolve 'fs'** issue I am not able to do the things further, it is giving me error on `const Minio = require("minio");` only. I tried deleting node module and package-lock and installing again but that didn't help me.

Comment: https://github.com/minio/minio-js/issues/718 Does this help?

Comment: @Piyush I am not able to generate minio-browser.js. I installed browserify using ```npm install browserify``` then did ```browserify minio.js```. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. that solution is, in your root folder you should create a `config-overrides.js` file. And just inside the `config-overrides.js` file write the below code.

***config-overrides.js***

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {   
    fs: require.resolve("browserify-fs"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
  });

  return config;
};
```